# How much impact will NGINX rewrite rules have on performance

Tags: nginx

I have a website served by NGINX, with ~1000 rewrite rules which ensure pages which existed before the website was completely rewritten are honoured.

Things like:

```
location ~ ^/old/page/?$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new permanent;}
location ~ ^/old/page2/?$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new2 permanent;}
location ~ ^/old/page3/$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new3 permanent;}
location ~ ^/another$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new4 permanent;}
```

I'm wondering how much time it might take the webserver to process these rules with each request (ballpark).  The server is performance-bound by uwsgi, not nginx, so the rules aren't taking up a lot of CPU. But could they add a noticeable chunk to each request's response time?  Or are they processed so quickly that a thousand could take a millisecond?  I'm trying to figure out if there's any value in winnowing them down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thousand of NGINX "regular expression" locations can absolutely have a performance penalty. Specifically how much this would be in time measurement, depends on the hardware and workload of your server.

Note that most of the regular locations you mentioned can be rewritten to exact matching, like I mention [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-locations-performance-impact-and-optimizations):

E.g. instead of:

```
location ~ ^/old/page/?$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new permanent;}
```

You can use:

```
location = /old/page/ { return 301 /new; }
location = /old/page { return 301 /new; }
```

This alone would be a huge improvement if you rewrite this way for thousands of locations like that.

Although, if you can reduce most of your locations by leveraging regular expressions better, it might provide a cleaner/shorter config with less performance impact than original config (fewer regular expression locations = better, but note that exact matching is still going to be faster):

E.g. you could replace:

```
location ~ ^/old/page/?$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new permanent;}
location ~ ^/old/page2/?$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new2 permanent;}
location ~ ^/old/page3/$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new3 permanent;}
```

with something like:

```
location ~ ^/old/page(\d+)?/?$ {rewrite ^(.*)$ /new$1 permanent;}
```

Either way, make sure to use `pcre_jit on;` as it helps NGINX to "pre-compile" regular expressions used for location matching.